# Как получить список временных зон на разных языках (PHP)?

Tags: php, icu

При регистрации пользователя хочу предложить выбор его временной зоны (часового пояса). Но при этом список временных зон показывать на родном пользователю языке (локаль "ru_RU", либо "en_US", либо какая угодно).
Насколько я понимаю, необходимо лезть в ICU чтобы получить канонические названия временных зон. И потом уже мержить массивы из разных локалей. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Локализовать скорее всего придётся вручную..

Comment: То есть самостоятельно перевести все названия часовых поясов? Но тогда при смене библиотеки ICU нужно будет снова вмешиваться в код. Вот один человек вытягивал из библиотеки некоторые данные по локалям: [http://intl.rmcreative.ru/site/zone-data?locale=ru_RU](http://intl.rmcreative.ru/site/zone-data?locale=ru_RU) В этой библиотеке на самом деле очень много данных. Нужно просто уметь их достать. На сайте есть поиск по любой локали.

Comment: Мда, жесть какая-то: https://3v4l.org/WK1rV

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо, где-то близко.Но возвращает  0 => string 'Jan 1, 1970, 3:00:00 AM Moscow Standard Time' (length=44)
  1 => string 'Jan 1, 1970, 3:00:00 AM Moscow Standard Time' (length=44) и так много раз подряд. Переменную $tz пришлось сделать null (во второй функции), так как выдает ошибку - конструктор неверный (PHP 7.0). Как это починить? И почему набор данных в массиве одинаковый?

Comment: Я и написал, что жесть, потому что в куче версий не работает. А какой разницы можно ожидать, если обнуллить единственный аргумент функции-маппера?

Comment: @vp_arth я не в самой анонимной функции обнулял, а дальше по коду там, где куча статики.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: @E_p как это использовать? https://3v4l.org/OCPqK Как сделать это на русском, например?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php

Comment: Я смотрел, но не понял как это поможет решению моей проблемы?

Comment: Спасибо, @vp_arth! На базе Ваше когда была решена задача.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы заработало. Ловится всего 6 исключений из 425 элементов.

```
$except = [];

$timezonesData = [];
$timezonesIdentifiers = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach ($timezonesIdentifiers as $timezone) {
    try {
        $formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
            "en_US",
            \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
            \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
            $timezone,
            \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
            'zzzz - ZZZZ - vvvv - VV - VVV - VVVV'
        );

        if ($formatter) {
            $t10n = $formatter->format(0);
        } else {
            $except[] = 'exception 1 '.$e->getMessage(); // continue;
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        $except[] = 'exception 2 '.$e->getMessage(); // continue;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $except[] = 'exception 3 '.$e->getMessage(); // continue;
    }

    $timezonesData[$timezone] = $t10n;
}
var_dump($except);

var_dump($timezonesData);
```

Стоит отметить, что должно быть установлено расширение PHP - intl с библиотекой ICU (поновее).
Дальше преобразовать текущий код и, я думаю, нетрудно будет получить список в том виде, который нужен. Всем спасибо.